# .htaccess: force www on all pages, force https on one page, force http on all other pages

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I have this site, example.com. What I want to do is force www on all pages, force https on one page, force http on all other pages.

I am using the following .htaccess code to redirect all http traffic to www:

```
#Redirect to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and the following to set SSL on my "form" page:

```
#Force SSL on a specific directory
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} form
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/form/$1 [R,L]
```

Problem is, when I hit https://example.com/, it does not redirect to www (https://www.example.com), and especially not http and www (http://www.example.com) like I want it to. I tried this:

```
#Redirect SSL to www
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

but that was a really dumb attempt and didn't work. How can I accomplish all three at once?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Handle nonSSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
RewriteRule !^/?form(/|$) http://www.ravicti.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Handle SSL 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^/?form(/|$) https://www.ravicti.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]    

# Add the missing www for both HTTP and HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ravicti.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}:s (on:(s)|off:s)
RewriteRule (.*) http%2://www.ravicti.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```